# i'm not processing more than one block correctly

Tags: c

I have an assignment where I'm suppose to read input lines such as

```
2
67 5 100 1 11 97 98 10 1 110
15 72 10 101 47 67 88 20 94 6 22 11

4
61 11 93 4 73 39 78 34 17 104
23 43 11 93 65 52 20 96 66 31 86 24 40 61 102 13 50 51
73 43 28 73 8 89 31 68 77 27 24 77 42 72 15 24 64 51
25 75 7 90 10 111 17 16
```

.....

process every two integers (the first line in a block only tells us how many words we will process), add them then match 
them to their corresponding ASCII char. The example above would be two blocks. 
The output should be:

```
 Decoded messages:
 Hello World!
 Happy Bhutanese teacher's day!
```

I'm having problems when it comes to dealing with a file with multiple blocks, more than 20 and so forth following the same format on one input text. I can handle one block fine, two blocks okay but not fine because my program doesn't seem to end. No line will be longer than 256 characters. numOfPuzzl refers to how many words we process per block.
I'd greatly appreciate any help. I attached my code and commented as much as I can too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //user will type in file name they choose to process and we allocated  in filename[]
    char filename[256];
    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    //process filename username typed in
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(filename, "r");

    //if there's nothong to read
    if (pFile == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Decoded messages:\n");

    //create array we will putting lines into
    char myString[256];
    //simply gets the first line, which is always a lone integer
    fgets(myString, 256, pFile);

    int numOfPuzzl;
    sscanf(myString, "%d", &numOfPuzzl);
    //printf("puzzles to solve: %d\n", numOfPuzzl);
    int wordsProcessed = 0;

    //just remember that myString has entire line

    //start processing the lines that follow, a line is a word
    while (fgets(myString, 256, pFile) != NULL){
        int num = 0; //first integer in line
        int secondNum = 0;  //second int. in line
        int tot = 0;  //how many bytes
        int bytes_read = 0; //bytes processed

        char *endOfStrAdr = strchr(myString, '\0');  //returns address of end terminating char.
        int endOfStrIdx = endOfStrAdr - myString;  //this will give me the index of where the terminating char. occurs within my array

        //start scanning integers within array making sure to not sccan out of bounds
        while (tot < endOfStrIdx){

            //first integer allocated as well as how many byes it was
            sscanf(myString + tot, "%d %n", &num, &bytes_read);

            tot += bytes_read;  //keeps tab so we don't have to read from the begn. of array everytime

            //second integer allocated as well as how many byes it was

            sscanf(myString + tot, "%d %n", &secondNum, &bytes_read);

            tot += bytes_read;   ////keeps tab so we don't have to read from the begn. of array everytime

            printf("%c", (char) num + secondNum); //add the two integers and cast them to char

            //we want to check if we are the end of the string, our word
            if (tot ==  endOfStrIdx){

                printf(" ");
                wordsProcessed++;
                //we want to print a new line char. if we finished processing all the words for the puzzle
                if (wordsProcessed == numOfPuzzl){
                    printf("\n");
                    fgets(myString, 256, pFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.  I also don't understand your question.

Comment: You mention the first line per puzzle tells how many words (lines?) there are, but your C program reads the very first integer as the number of puzzles. Shouldn't that number be in your example?

Comment: A more descriptive title would be a lot more helpful, btw.

Comment: Also - could it be that you have lines longer than 256 characters?

Comment: I realized I was misusing a word...hope this clarifies. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ignore blank lines between puzzles.
- Reset parameters (`numOfPuzzl` and `wordsProcessed`) before processing new puzzles.

To archive that, change

```
if (wordsProcessed == numOfPuzzl) {
    printf("\n");
    fgets(myString, 256, pFile);
}
```

into

```
if (wordsProcessed == numOfPuzzl) {
    printf("\n");
    while ( fgets(myString, 256, pFile) != NULL ){
        if ( sscanf(myString, "%d", &numOfPuzzl) == 1 )
            break;
    }
    wordsProcessed = 0;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to roll-back if you disagree with the edit.

Comment: thanks a lot! i'm not sure I understand though, the blocks i'm given are always separated by one blank line, so wouldn't the while loop first get a blank line. it would make perfect sense if the blocks were chunked together but their not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//stringize macro    
#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)

int main(void){
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX + 1];
    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf("%" S(FILENAME_MAX) "[^\n]", filename);

    FILE *pFile;
    if(NULL==(pFile = fopen(filename, "r"))){
        perror("can't opne file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Decoded messages:\n");
    int numOfLines;
    while(1==fscanf(pFile, "%d", &numOfLines)){
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfLines; ++i){
            int num1, num2, state;
            char ck;
            while(3==(state=fscanf(pFile, "%d %d%c", &num1, &num2, &ck)) || 2 == state){
                putchar(num1 + num2);
                if(state == 2 || state == 3 && ck == '\n')
                    break;
            }
            putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```